# Turn off "Low Stock Alert" for all Configurable Products

Tags: configurable-product, inventory, quantity

Wanna ask whether we can turn off "Low Stock Alert" that is being triggered every time customer places an order for Configurable Product?

In Inventory setting - there is no way to increase or decrease quantity of Configurable Product. And I believe quantity for Configurable Products are being set as "0" and that's why "Low Stock Alert" is triggered.

**Solution needed :** is there a way to prevent the "Low Stock Alert" global configuration to have its effect on Configurable Products? So that no notification mail is sent to respective vendor.

Comment: The configurable product quantity will always be 0 as the stock level is driven from the associated simple product. What is the quantity of your products linked to the configurable?